# Disable knockout.js custom binding from even being evaluated

Tags: knockout.js

If I want the editGame custom binding below in knockout.js to not be evaulated in some instances, how do I go about doing that?  I have a bit I can test against, but I dont know the approach to not run init/update.  I could send the bit in to make sure the internal logic doesnt run, but what if I dont event want that to run?

```
<div data-bind="editGame: { }">

</div>
```

Comment: We are going to need more information like what conditions would cause it to not run (or even an example one).  What is edit game doing?  Any more information you could give would help.

Comment: Its basically a click event. If there is a matchup for that slot, Id like it to be enabled, if not, then I dont want it to be clickable.

Comment: Maybe pass a parameter to an observable which stores whether there is a clickable item?  Then in the update you can use the valueAccessor parameter (its the second parameter passed) to access that observable and check it.